# ReferenceError: foundItems is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, callback

I don't understand why I am getting this error. Do we need to define foundItems somewhere else.
I believe foundItems is a callback and that name can be anything and doesn't need to be declared before in order to use it.

Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong here.

This is my code:

```
app.get("/",function(req,res)

{
  Item.find({},function(err,foundItems)

  {

    if(err)

    console.log(err);

    else

    {

          console.log(foundItems);

    }

  });

        if(foundItems.length===0)

        {

                Item.insertMany(defaultItems,function(err){

                  if(err)

                  console.log(err);

                  else

                  {

                    console.log("Inserted successfully into database");

                    res.redirect("/");

                  }

                });

        }

        else

        res.render('list',{ listTitle: "Today" ,newListItems : foundItems});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Scoping is the issue here. 
The foundItems is scoped to

```
 Item.find({},function(err,foundItems)

  {

    if(err)

    console.log(err);

    else

    {

          console.log(foundItems);

    }

  });
```

This block only. So you need to move your all code to this block.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But the problem was I accidentally copied the whole home route code and had the same code twice.